# angular msal v2 missing group claims

Tags: angular, msal-angular

I'm looking to upgrade my angular app from MSAL v1 to MSAL v2, and one problem I have is the jwt token that the guard adds to requests does not include the `group` field in the payload anymore.
We use group membership to decide who can access what so this is a big blocker of course.

Is there some client side config I'm missing required to get the group claims to show up in the token for MSAL v2 ? I've tried the scopes openid, user.read and profile, not sure if that's even where I should be looking.

Group claims do show up in MSAL v1 tokens, so I'm assuming the Azure config is valid.

EDIT: I'm being told the v1 token seems to be an id_token, and the v2 token is an access_token. Is there a way to get v2 to send the id_token instead of the access_token when using the Guard ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seemed to be the scope, I changed it from 'openid' to my $clientid/openid and it started working.